# How to Make a /22 Reverse Zone in Bind? (255.255.252.0))

Tags: bind

I'm working on a project to set up a Bind9 DNS server on a network with a 255.255.252.0 subnet.

Currently, the way it is set up makes it impossible to run nslookup
From 192.168.1.101/22 through ns1 @ 192.168.1.61/22 on a 192.168.0.0/22 network with a gateway of 192.168.1.1/22. Don't ask why I started addressing at 192.168.1.1 and not 192.168.0.1. I just did. Easier to type two 1s in a row but want extra address space. I put my dhcp wifi clients in the .2.1-255 range and run vms in the .3.1-255 range. The point is that it seems Bind seems to think all addresses @ 192.168.1.0-255 are from a separate /24 zone.

This bears to question, does a 0.168.192. reverse zone look like a /24 subnet by default in Bind? What about a 168.192. reverse zone? Are they all /16 zones to Bind?

Which returns me to my original question.

Despite all the errors in my Bind config, which would be good to know what I should do to fix them specifically, how do I achieve what I want to do?

How do you program Bind to host a /22, /21, or any nonstandard bitted zone?

Here is my reverse zone file in the raw.

```
$ttl 38400
0/22.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    IN  SOA ns.fqdn.com. user.emai.com. (
            1489024990
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
61.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN  NS  ns.fqdn.com.
61.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN  PTR ns.fqdn.com.
1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR fw.fqdn.com.
62.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN  PTR ws.fqdn.com.
63.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN  PTR multi.fqdn.com.
25.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.  IN  PTR fs.fqdn.com.
110.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa. IN  PTR thncl.fqdn.com.
```

The following errors were found in the BIND configuration file /etc/bind/named.conf or referenced zone files ..

```
 zone fqdn.com/IN: NS 'fqdn.com' has no address records (A or AAAA)
    zone fqdn.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
    _default/fqdn.com/IN: bad zone
    /var/lib/bind/192.168.0.rev:2: SOA record not at top of zone (0/22.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa)
    /var/lib/bind/192.168.0.rev:9: ignoring out-of-zone data (61.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa)
    /var/lib/bind/192.168.0.rev:10: ignoring out-of-zone data (1.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa)
    /var/lib/bind/192.168.0.rev:11: ignoring out-of-zone data (62.168.192.in-addr.arpa)
    /var/lib/bind/192.168.0.rev:12: ignoring out-of-zone data (63.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa)
    /var/lib/bind/192.168.0.rev:13: ignoring out-of-zone data (25.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa)
    /var/lib/bind/192.168.0.rev:14: ignoring out-of-zone data (110.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa)
    zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file /var/lib/bind/192.168.0.rev failed: not at top of zone
    zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.
    _default/0.168.192.in-addr.arpa/IN: not at top of zone
```

This being said, the only thing I can think of is to expand the zone to a 168.192. zone and put an ACL that limits lookups to the /22 subnet, leaving the zone file expanded and open.

Any help is appreciated, Server Buddies!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the scheme defined for mapping IPv4 addresses to reverse DNS names ([RFC 1035 §3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.5)), it not possible to do delegations that are not at the **/8**, **/16** or **/24** boundaries.

For networks larger than **/24**, you'd simply delegate multiple zones of the closest smaller size.

So your **/22** network would be put into four consecutive **/24** zones:

- `0.168.192.in-addr.arpa`
- `1.168.192.in-addr.arpa`
- `2.168.192.in-addr.arpa`
- `3.168.192.in-addr.arpa`

---

For smaller than **/24** networks, a bit of a clever hack defined in [RFC 2317](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2317) is used, where in the parent zone `CNAME` records are added for the names belonging to each individual IP address of the smaller network, pointing all of these into a new namespace and then delegating that namespace instead.

Comment: Nice explanation!  Thanks!